# Will this small crease in passport be a problem

Tags: passports

[image]

Will this crease be a problem when travelling

Comment: I know people (frequent travelers) carrying their passport in the back pocket of their jeans, throughout the complete travel, and after some years they look like they were run over by a tank. Never an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that this will cause an issue.

Passports are typically issued for 10 years. To expect them to be in pristine condition at the end of that period is unreasonable.

Answer (score 5):

I’m not an immigration/customs officer, but I highly doubt this would be a problem. It’s on the outside so it doesn’t look like some potential tampering. My passport probably looks worse and I’ve had no problems.

Answer (score 1):

It will absolutely not be a problem.

To make you feel better, here's my story. My old passport was in a very terrible state after having spilled some Pepsi from KFC on it. The problem was that I only realised a couple of weeks later when I took it from its drawer and the pages were all wet, sticky and smelly. The biodata page was not damaged, but every single other page had a huge brown stain on it and an unpleasant smell (which fortunately went away after I "cleaned" it and dried it). I still used that passport for a few more years until it expired and I was only asked about the damage once, and after laughing at my story the border agent told be to be more careful.